# Split a list with consecutive block items but discontinued blocks into sub-lists

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have a list like this:

`mylist = [2,3,4,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,10,11,12,20,19,18,17,17,18,19,20,21]`

I want to split it into sub-lists like this:

```
sublist_1 = [2,3,4]
sublist_2 = [7,8,9]
sublist_3 = [0,1,2,3]
sublist_4 = [10,11,12]
sublist_5 = [20,19,18,17]
sublist_5 = [17,18,19,20,21]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should avoid making many variables which differ just by a subscript. In many cases, it is better to add them all in a list, and then use list-indexing to get the sublist you want: `sublists = [[2,3,4], [7,8,9], ..., [17,18,19,20,21]]`. Then if you want for example to print the second sublist (note that Python uses 0-based indexing), you can do `print(sublists[1])`.

Comment: And what is the expected answer if `mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]`? Is that `[1, 2, 3, 4]; [3, 2, 1]` or `[1, 2, 3]; [4, 3, 2, 1]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]`?

Comment: @BasSwinckels Thanks for reminding me, I didn't recognize that case before you mentioned it. This problem is originated from my communicate network,  if sequence of packets lost in the wire, the received packet will be discontinued like this `[ 20,21,23,29,30,31,0,1]`. I  expand it to a more general case and try to figure out the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code -

```
mylist = [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 20, 19, 18, 17, 17, 18, 19,
          20, 21]

result = []

temp_list = [mylist[0]]

for i in range(1, len(mylist)):
    if abs(mylist[i] - mylist[i - 1]) != 1:
        result.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = [mylist[i]]
    else:
        temp_list.append(mylist[i])

if temp_list:
    result.append(temp_list)

print(result)
```

Output -

```
[[2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12], [20, 19, 18, 17],
 [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do;

```
mylist = [2,3,4,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,10,11,12,20,19,18,17,17,18,19,20,21]

index =0
for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
    #print (mylist[i+1])
    if (i+1 >= len(mylist)):
        print (mylist[index:i+1])
        break

    if not( (mylist[i+1] - mylist[i] == 1) or (mylist[i+1] - mylist[i] == -1) ):
        print (mylist[index:i+1])
        index = i+1
```

Output

```
[2, 3, 4]
[7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[10, 11, 12]
[20, 19, 18, 17]
[17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `numpy` approach. I'm using [ediff1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html),
[intersect1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html), [nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

```
import numpy as np
mylist = [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 20, 19, 18, 17, 17, 18, 19,
          20, 21]
a = np.array(mylist)
t = np.ediff1d(mylist)
i = np.intersect1d(np.nonzero(t!=-1), np.nonzero(t!=1))
rslt = np.split(a,i+1)


rslt
Out[70]: 
[array([2, 3, 4]),
 array([7, 8, 9]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 array([10, 11, 12]),
 array([20, 19, 18, 17]),
 array([17, 18, 19, 20, 21])]
```

if you want the output to be `list` instead of `numpy array`, change the last line to `rslt = [x.tolist() for x in np.split(a,i+1)]`, the result will be

```
rslt
Out[9]: 
[[2, 3, 4],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [10, 11, 12],
 [20, 19, 18, 17],
 [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
```